# Spatial queries by webgis and virtualizing

Tags: web-mapping

I have a question regarding this tutorial:

http://www.gistutor.com/postgresqlpostgis/10-intermediate-postgresqlpostgis-tutorials/75-understanding-postgis-spatial-queries.html

As you can see, it demonstrates how spatial sql statements are working.

How was this tutorial with this webgis built up?

I know that openlayers,json,php,wfs-t,ajax and postgis comes into the play but how all these componentes are working together.

Is there any good tutorial out there or can somebody gives workshops?